failed to fetch in jupyter notebook
i tried
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv("AB_NYC_2019.csv")
df.head(3)

and it is saying failed to fetch file save error for untitled.ipynb
I have also tried
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv("C:\Users\device_name\anaconda3\AB_NYC_2019.csv")
df.head(3)

but no results

@mozway the first code producing the original error has nothing to do with the linked duplicate. The dup only covers OPs attempt to fix the error

Gopal, you need to provide more details for us to be able to help you. And you might even solve the issue yourself along the way. For example, we need the exact error traceback you see. Or at at least most of it. 'Fetch' is not something that should be involved in what you present thus far because you act like in the second code block it is on your local drive. So I'd expect file not found or something about the path. So run ls in your notebook and show us what it says, or you shouldn't expect df = pd.read_csv("AB_NYC_2019.csv") to work. Also running pwd might help you sort this.
